# Whats the best way to find the "next but one newest" date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server that holds data organised by BusinessDataDate.  BusinessDataDate is a Date only (no time component) and is only populated on Business days. e.g. not Weekends or public holidays.

Because there is no specific order to this, I want to find the `date before the current max date`

This query works, and I can set the values into local variables - but it feels like there must be a cleaner way?

```
SELECT MAX(BusinessDataDate) FROM myTable 
  WHERE BusinessDataDate < (SELECT MAX(BusinessDataDate) FROM myTable)
```

Each date will have multiple rows in the table - the exact number is not predictable.

Comment: Your approach is fine.  Adding a where clause to both the main and subquery to filter on only the last x days might improve performance.

Comment: I might try that...however, working in Middle East its a little vague to guess.  Eid can be 3-6 days, and if it coincides with weekends then affectively you could have a 10 day range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to your original query but how about using top 1?

```
SELECT Top 1 BusinessDataDate 
FROM myTable 
WHERE BusinessDataDate < (SELECT MAX(BusinessDataDate) FROM myTable)
ORDER BY BusinessDataDate DESC
```

Comment: You'll need ORDER BY on outer query

Comment: How is it better? This will require sort, and original query will not.

Comment: Just checked and all three have 0% operator cost, but this one has 0.006 Subtree cost - original one 0.06 and dense_rank 0.08.  Hey, they are all quick and simple, but I like the last one as being more readable than my original.

Comment: So the cost of this query is less expensive than the other two and yet I still received 2 downvotes? I'd like to understand why that is..

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TOP (1)
    BusinessDataDate
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        BusinessDataDate,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY BusinessDataDate DESC) as rn
    FROM
        myTable
    ) x
WHERE
    x.rn = 2
ORDER BY
    x.BusinessDataDate;
```

Comment: Should have said - there are multiple rows in the table - the exact number of rows differs per date.

Comment: @BlueChippy: be specific then, don't downvote. Easily fixed if **we had known**

Comment: I didn't downvote...but it's still incorrect as x is not a column name..think it should be rn?

Comment: x is not a column name.  It's an alias for the subquery which effectively makes it a tablename.

Comment: I suspect at least one down-vote was "payback" based on an assumption.